# Find $T^* $, where $T$ is the linear operator defined by $T \epsilon_1 = (1, - 2), \,\,T\epsilon_2 =(i, - 1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, adjoint-operators

Let $V$ be the space $\mathbb C^2$, with the standard inner product. Let $T$ be the linear
operator defined by $T \epsilon_1 = (1, - 2), \,\,\ T\epsilon_2 = (i, - 1)$. If  $ \alpha = (x_1, x_2)$, find $T^* \alpha$.

**Attempt:** 
Because the base $ \{ \epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \}$ is orthonormal, I know that the matrix of $T^*$ is the conjugate transpose of the matrix of $T$ (in the same basis). Then

$$[T^*]=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2\\-i & -1\end{pmatrix}$$.

Therefore

$T^* \epsilon_1 = (1, - i), \,\,\ T^* \epsilon_2 = (-2, - 1)$

and

$T^* \alpha= T^* (x_1,x_2)=x_1T^* \epsilon_1  + x_2T^*\epsilon_2= x_1(1, - i) +x_2(-2, - 1)= (x_1 - 2x_2, -ix_1 -x_2)$.

Is this right?

Comment: Because? Is not it just transpose and conjugate the $T$ matrix?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy each input of the matrix of $T^*$ is given by, say $B_{ij} = \bar{A_{ji}}$ according to what is in Hoffman's book, where $A_{ij}$ are the entrances of the matrix of $T$. The matrix of $T$ is $$[T]=\begin{pmatrix}1 & i\\-2 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$, then the matrix of $T^*$ is $$[T^*]=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2\\-i & -1\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: Sorry, the confusion was between so called left and right hand notations.

Comment: No problems! thanks for listening!